# How to set AJAX response to jquery data table columns?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

Can anyone tell me how to set the response to jquery data to each table columns.

Here is my javascript code:

```
$(document).ready (function() {
$.ajax({
    url: 'userController?action=list',
    success : function(response) {
        var jsonObject = $.parseJSON(response); 
        alert(jsonObject.Password);
        alert(jsonObject.UserId);
        $('#usertable').dataTable( {
            data : jsonObject,
            columns: [
                      {'jsonObject' : 'UserId'},
                      {'jsonObject' : 'Password'},
                      {'jsonObject' : 'Level'},               
                      ],
            searching : false
        });
    }
});});
```

Here the response in String and the response is 
`{"UserId" : "Manohar", "Password" : "1234", "Level" : "lev"}`.

Below is the jsp page.

```
<table id="usertable">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>User Id</th>
        <th>Password</th>
        <th>Level</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

I have written the above and neither I am getting error nor the row is added to table. Can you guys help me in this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here the solution is to change the response.
Earlier it was {"userid":"manohar", "password":"1234"}, now I have changed it to [["manohar", "1234"]].
Then in js file

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'userController?action=list',
    success : function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        var table_data = JSON.parse(data);
        var table = $('#usermaintenancetable').DataTable( {
            data: table_data
}); } });
```

So here the response is in String format and I have change it to JSON using JSON.parse() then passed this as data to data table.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't reinitialize the datatable inside your success method. Once you have the json object response, you should use [row.add()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row.add()) method,

Sol 1: (For looping JSON objects)

```
success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    $.each(data, function (i,item) {
        var rowNode= [ item.UserId, item.Password, item.Level]
        dataTable.row.add(rowNode).draw();
    }); 
}
```

Sol 2 :(For JSON string values)

```
success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
        var rowNode= [ jsonData.UserId, jsonData.Password, jsonData.Level]
        dataTable.row.add(rowNode).draw();
}
```

The above code adds one row at a time. For adding multiple rows at once, use [rows.add()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows.add()) API method

Comment: with above code I am getting below error **jquery.js:569 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in {"UserId" : "lin", "Password" : "1111", "Level" : "admin"}**

Comment: still no luck :( Getting undefined error for item.UserId (for all). When I am accessing it outside of the $.each(), I can able to print **JSON.parse(data).UserId** but not able to add row to data table.

Comment: @manohare Ok then simply try without item. Try my alternative code.

Comment: The `$.each` is for looping through multiple objects since you are returning single json string you don't need to loop and the json respone is not an object. Instead its key value json string. So try my Sol2. It should work.

Comment: That is also not working. Getting error: **datatable.js:11 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined**
Below is the code that I have used:
`success : function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
   alert(data);
   var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
   alert(jsonData.userid);
   var rowNode = [jsonData.UserId, jsonData.Password, jsonData.Level];
   var userTable = $('#usermaintenancetable').dataTable();
   userTable.row.add(rowNode).draw();
  }`

Comment: @manohare That mean the above code works. The error just means that you have problem in your datatable plugin import. Post your html where you load you datatable js. Please make sure you use the latest version and use datatable after loading jquery. And use `$('#usertable').DataTable( {` instead of the `dataTable` which is an old version.

Comment: Or Do you have a reference for datatable object in your code before the ajax call? If so please post your code.

Comment: Thanks Lucky. I have changed the response. Instead of {"UserId": "name", "Password":"12345"}, used [["name", "12345"]]. And then parsed it with JSON.parse(data). With this approach it is working fine :)

Answer (score 0):

> use this

```
$(document).ready (function() {
$.ajax({
    url: 'userController?action=list',
    success : function(response) {
        var jsonObject = $.parseJSON(response); 
        alert(jsonObject.Password);
        alert(jsonObject.UserId);
        $('#usertable').dataTable( {
            data : jsonObject,
            //data : response,
            columns: [
                      {"data" : "UserId"},
                      {"data" : "Password"},
                      {"data" : "Level"}              
                      ],
            searching : false
        });
    }
});});
```

change only `jsonObject` to `data`

> Try Another Method u can use ASP.NET MVC

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $.get("/userController/list", function (data) {
        //  console.log(data);
        if (data != null) {
             $('#usertable').dataTable({                           
                       data: data,
                       columns: [
                                 {"data" : "UserId"},
                                 {"data" : "Password"},
                                 {"data" : "Level"}              
                                ],
                      searching : false
                      });
                    }
                })
            });
```

Comment: I tried the this approach also but not working. And there are no errors on the console.

Comment: you have any data `alert(jsonObject.Password);`

Comment: try this `data : jsonObject,` change `data : response,`

Comment: I am working with Spring MVC. Actually I am able to get the response but the same is not able applying to data tables.